# Java URLConnection.getURL() only redirects after seemingly unconnected methods are called

Tags: java, urlconnection

The following piece of code should print out the new location of a website that uses the `Location` header to redirect to a new page/file (`http://somepagethatredirects.me/after.txt`):

```
URL website = new URL("http://somepagethatredirects.me/before.txt");
URLConnection urlConnection = website.openConnection();
System.out.println(urlConnection.getURL());
```

Even though we expect the location to be `http://somepagethatredirects.me/after.txt`, we get the URL parameter specified.

Adding a (seemingly unconnected) method like `urlConnection.getHeaderField("Location")`, `urlConnection.getHeaderFields()` or even `urlConnection.getExpiration()` will (strangely) give us the expected result:

```
URL website = new URL("http://somepagethatredirects.me/before.txt");
URLConnection urlConnection = website.openConnection();
urlConnection.getHeaderFields();
System.out.println(urlConnection.getURL());
```

Is this intended behaviour? It seems like a bug to me.

---

**Edit 1**:
As Jeffrey Bosbom pointed out, calling `urlConnection.openConnection()` doesn't actually establish a connection to the server, `urlConnection.connect()` does (or other methods that imply an active connection). This doesn't change the program's output however:

```
URL website = new URL("http://somepagethatredirects.me/before.txt");
URLConnection urlConnection = website.openConnection();
urlConnection.connect();
System.out.println(urlConnection.getURL());
```

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom good idea, but `urlConnection.connect()` doesn't "update" the URL either, I just checked it. I'll add it to the methods in the question and write another piece of example code.

Comment: [URLConnection.getURL()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getURL()) returns the the original url which you connect to, not the `Location` header, you can't read anything from the url which you are connecting to until you have established a connection by calling `connect`

Comment: @Dummy I don't get why `urlConnection.getURL()` returns the new URL I've been redirected to after calling `urlConnection.getHeaderFields()` or `urlConnection.getExpiration()` then, though.

Comment: That is strange because the behaviour is not consistent with the API docs, you might wanna peek into the source for those methods to see what's really going on. But `getURL()` should never return anything other than the original url you connected to as per the docs .e.g. it returns the protected field url passed to `URLConnection` class constructor

Comment: @Dummy as you can read in the original question, I was wondering the same; I didn't expect to see those results. You can try and execute it on your own PC with some page that does a `Location` redirect. For some odd reason, `urlConnection.getHeaderFields()` or any methods I listed seem to modify the URL field.

Comment: I would like to test this out if Im not on my tablet. But could you insert a call to `connect()` after `urlConnection.getHeaderFields()` to see if you get any error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132043/discussion-between-linkd-and-dummy).

Answer (score 0):

Nothing happens in terms of HTTP transactions until you either:

- get the response code
- open the input stream
- open the error stream.

I'm not sure that even after that you have any basis for expecting `getURL()` to deliver the final target URL.